# How can I hide and protect the text of one Cell in an excel file using openxml with c# (not the entire row/ column)?

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm not sure if it is possible to hide and protect the data of a specific cell in excel file using openxml(not the entire row or column). 
Anyone have an idea about that please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Protection Class:

```
public class Protection : OpenXmlLeafElement
```

**18.8.33 protection (Protection Properties)**

> Contains protection properties associated with the cell. Each cell has
>   protection properties that can be set. The cell protection properties
>   do not take effect unless the sheet has been protected.

**hidden (Hidden Cell)**

> A boolean value indicating if the cell is hidden. When the cell is
>   hidden and the sheet on which the cell resides is protected, then the
>   cell value is displayed in the cell grid location, but the contents of
>   the cell will not be displayed in the formula bar. This is true for
>   all types of cell content, including formula, text, or numbers.
>
> Therefore the cell A4 can contain a formula "=SUM(A1:A3)", but if the
>   cell protection property of A4 is marked as hidden, and the sheet is
>   protected, then the cell should display the calculated result
>   [Example: "6" end example], but will not display the formula used to
>   calculate the result.
>
> The possible values for this attribute are defined by the W3C XML
>   Schema boolean datatype.

**locked (Cell Locked)**

> A boolean value indicating if the cell is locked. When cells are
>   marked as "locked" and the sheet is protected, then the options
>   specified in the Sheet Part's sheetProtection element (§18.3.1.85) are
>   prohibited for these cells.
>
> The possible values for this attribute are defined by the W3C XML
>   Schema boolean datatype.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc798966%28v%3Doffice.14%29

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I tried to apply a protection to the cell as you said. but it doesn't work :
Here what I did:

Protection protection = new Protection { Hidden = true, Locked = true };
Cell addedCell = ExcelInteropManager.UpdateCell(worksheet, "C", 1,"Hello");
addedCell.Append(protection);